# Why is there no `.split!` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

It just seems pretty logical to have it when there's even a `downcase!`. Has anyone else run into this use case in Ruby?

For the curious, I'm trying to do this:

```
def some_method(foo)
  foo.downcase!.split!(" ")
## do some stuff with foo later. ##
end

some_method("A String like any other")
```

Instead of this:

```
 def some_method(foo)
   foo = foo.downcase.split(" ")
 ## do some stuff with foo later. ##
 end

 some_method("A String like any other")
```

Which isn't a really big deal...but `!` just seems cooler.

Comment: You are attempting to replace a string with an array. You can replace a string with a differerent string or an array with an different array, but you cannot replace an instance of one class with an instance of another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is there no `.split!` in Ruby?
>
> It just seems pretty logical to have it when there's even a `downcase!`.

It may be logical, but it is impossible: objects cannot change their class or their identity in Ruby. You may be thinking of Smalltalk's `become:` which doesn't and *cannot* exist in Ruby. `become:` changes the identity of an object and thus can also change its class.

Comment: Why do you emphasize "cannot"?

Comment: Because from experience, the very next question becomes: "Okay, there is no `become` in Ruby, how can I write one?"

Comment: How about the `=` operator. `a = 1; a = '2'`. `a` has been changed from an integer to a string.

Comment: @ReggieB: `a` is a variable. Variables aren't objects. Variables don't have classes. Variables point to objects. And variables can point to different objects over time, that's what makes them "variable".

Comment: _"how can I write one?""_ – well, you could implement `Object#become` via a C extension. It's a bad idea, but it _can_ be done.

Comment: @Stefan: Sure, but a) you aren't writing one in Ruby, and b) the resulting interpreter is no longer an interpreter for Ruby. Oh, and c) it's probably not going to work in Rubinius, JRuby, IronRuby, Opal, Topaz, MagLev, RubyMotion, MRuby, …

Comment: I see. The "Ruby" in _"cannot exist in Ruby"_ refers to Ruby code, not the language itself. At first I thought there was a fundamental technical limitation or barrier within the language which prevents such a method.

Comment: @Stefan: Well, the "limitation" is that it would no longer be Ruby. Also, I really doubt that you could implement it with a C extension, at least not using the official API. `become` has deep implications for the garbage collector, the object memory, the thread scheduler, the optimizer, the compiler, and other components of the VM, and most of those are not accessible using the official C extension API. (And I'm not even talking about implementing it efficiently, just implementing it *at all*.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this "use case" as very important.

The only thing a "bang method" is doing is saving you the trouble of assigning a variable.

The reason "bang methods" are the exception instead of the rule is they can produce confusing results if you don't understand them.

i.e. if you write

```
a = "string"
def my_upcase(string)
  string.upcase!
end
b = my_upcase(a)
```

then both `a` and `b` will have transformed value even if you didn't intend to change `a`. Removing the exclamation point fixes this example, but if you're using mutable objects such as hashes and arrays you'll have to look out for this in other situations as well.

```
a = [1,2,3]
def get_last_element(array)
  array.pop
end
b = get_last_element(a)
```

Since `Array#pop` has side effects, `a` is now `1,2`. It has the last element removed, which might not have been what you intended. You could replace `.pop` here with `[-1]` or `.last` to get rid of the side effect

The exclamation point in a method name is essentially warning you that there are side effects. This is important in the concept of functional programming, which prescribes side effect free code. Ruby is very much a functional programming language by design (although it's very object oriented as well).

If your "use case" boils down to avoiding assigning a variable, that seems like a really minor discomfort.

For a more technical reason, though, see Jorg Mittag's answer. It's impossible to write a method which changes the class of `self`

Answer (score 0):

this

```
 def some_method(foo)
   foo = foo.downcase.split(" ")
 end

 some_method("A String like any other")
```

is the same as this

```
def some_method(foo)
 foo.downcase.split
end
some_method("A String like any other")
```

Comment: Ahh sorry let me fix my explanation. I use the foo object again in the method so I need to change foo, not just return it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, both of your methods return the same result. We can look at a few examples of methods that modify the caller.

```
array.map! return a modified original array
string.upcase! return a modified original string
```

However,

`split` modifies the class of the caller, changing a string to an array.

Notice how the above examples only modify the content of the object, instead of changing its class.

This is most likely why there isn't a `split!` method, although it's pretty easy to define one yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention that I do stuff with foo later, rather than return it. Sorry!

Comment: it really has to do with changing the object's class

Answer (score 0):

#split creates an array out of a string, you can't permanently mutate(!) the string into being an array. Because the method is creating a new form from the source information(string), the only thing you need to do to make it permanent, is to bind it to a variable.